# Help proving the product of 1+ positive real numbers is greater than its sum

Tags: inequality, products

I am trying to prove the following inequality: Given real numbers $a_i\geq0, i=1,2,\ldots n$, then $\prod^n_{i=1}(1+a_i)\geq \sum^n_{i=1} a_i$.

I've tried to do it using induction but I wasn't able to conclude the argument. Is there a simple proof for this? It seems natural, since one of the components of the product will be $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ but I am not able to show it rigorously.

Comment: Can you break up the product on the LHS into pieces, one of which is the sum on the right?

Comment: If you are trying to do using induction, it might be easier to show that $\prod_{i =1}^n(1 + a_i) \geq 1 + \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i$.

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful!